# Can I offer a dark mode in my "static" HTML file withotu any "dynamic" features such as JavaScript or input buttons?

Tags: html, darkmode

I am preparing a self-contained HTML file: it has no links to external CSS files. I want to apply the old philosophy that HTML should only contain the contents of the document (paragraphs, sections, lists, tables) whereas the formatting (such as background color, choice of font) should not be my concern: the readers should be able to change them fairly easily themselves. The contents of my HTML look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style><!-- nothing in it --></style>
  <title>My HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My HTML</h1>
    <p> I would like the contents to adapt the default theme of the browser.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is rendered with black font against the white background. I would expect that if the reader selected the dark theme in their browser, it would render with different colors. But this is not the case: my HTML is always displayed with black font against the white background.

I know that I could change it with some "dynamic" aspects of HTML, such as JavaScript functions or input buttons that trigger actions. But I want to avoid these because of my philosophy: HTML should just be data -- formatting should be done externally.

Is there a way to achieve my goal in HTML? Or is my philosophy incompatible with what HTML is?

Comment: See [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)

Comment: You can add CSS that will apply a dark theme when then OS/browser is in dark mode. The browser does _not_ have an implicit default dark CSS.

Comment: Styling is done via CSS. It is not something you can do in HTML. Add a css file and use `prefers-color-scheme`

Comment: Yes, it is possible, there are some turnarounds like using a checkbox and verify if it is clicked in CSS and applying the corresponding styles. also, you might use **prefers-color-scheme**. Just google it and you will find a good articles about it